# SQL - How to echo out <div></div> inside of where statement

Tags: php, wpdb

In my query, is it possible to echo out a php value? If not, is there any way just to pass in the value of the id player_id?

```
<?php
$New = '<p id="player_id"></p>';

// This outputs the correct value. How can I output
// what is inside of the <p> tag into the SQL Query?
echo $New


$A = 'LRAR';
   
$Class_Data = $wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT FLA, Date, Location_Name FROM Class_Date
        INNER JOIN Class_Location
        ON Class_Date.Location_ID = 
        Class_Location.Central_Location_ID
        INNER JOIN Course
        ON Class_Date.CourseID = Course.CourseID
        WHERE FLA = %s", $A);
        
        $Class_Data_Results =$wpdb->get_results( $Class_Data );
```

Outputting $A works fine, but I want to be able to output $New. How can I set my query to be equal to a value with HTML tags included?

Comment: You really should look into [`$wpdb::prepare()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) and read through the [WPDB Dev page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/)

Comment: Thank you for that. I was able to output simple strings such as $a = 'Some stuff here'. However, I am finding it difficult to be able to print out whole html tags. For instance, $a = '<p>Some stuff here</p>'